# What version of openssh is compatible with openssl 1.0.2t?

Tags: openssl, openssh

I want to know what version of openssh is compatible with openssl 1.0.2t

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

openssl is a dependency of openssh. (In fact, it's optional) You can basically build openssh with whatever version of openssl you want.

AFAIK, most distros have already migrated to openssl 1.1. You have to build an openssh depending on openssl 1.0 by yourself.